# How to combine more than one list into more than one dicts by using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, tags

Sorry that I have to ask this question if it's a rather easy one, as time's limited for this script..I've already written some codes like below:

```
localNames = re.findall(r"<\*\[local-name\(\)='.*?'.*?\/@\*\[name\(\)='.*?'.*?'\]", str(nontransTagsContent[0]))
for i in localNames:
tags = re.findall(r"local-name\(\)='(.*?)'", i)
attributes = re.findall(r"name\(\)='(.*?)'", i)
```

And the result for `print(tags)` is below:

```
['tag1']
['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']
['tag5', 'tag6']
```

The result for `print(attributes)` is below:

```
['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4']
['attribute5', 'attribute6']
['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']
```

The result I want to get is dictionaries like:

```
{'tag1':['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3','attribute4'}
{'tag2':['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag3':['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag4':['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag5':['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']}
{'tag6':['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']}
```

I thought in this way, I can manipulate the data easily as I can extract data and write them into other forms. Below is the code I tried:

```
for x in tags:
    dict = zip(tags, attributes)
    print (list(dict))
```

But the output doesn't seem to be right. Would you help take a look at it and see how to fix this...Thank you very much!

Comment: Are the tags and attributes *per line* are guaranteed to be unique? In other words, does `'attribute1'` will only occur at line1?

Comment: post your `localNames` content

Comment: That's a good question. I think the tags should be unique, but the attributes may not be.

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest I added the codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tags=[ 
    ['tag1'],
    ['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'],
    ['tag5', 'tag6'],
  ]

  attributes=[
              ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4'],
              ['attribute5', 'attribute6'],
              ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9'],
            ]

  for idx, tag_line in enumerate(tags):
    for tag in tag_line:
      print {tag : attributes[idx]}
```

output:

```
{'tag1': ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4']}
{'tag2': ['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag3': ['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag4': ['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag5': ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']}
{'tag6': ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']}
```

if you want the dict has all the tag in one list

```
  from itertools import repeat
  for tag, attr in zip(tags,attributes):
    print dict(zip(tag, repeat(attr,len(tag))))
```

output:

```
{'tag1': ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4']}
{'tag4': ['attribute5', 'attribute6'], 'tag2': ['attribute5', 'attribute6'], 'tag3': ['attribute5', 'attribute6']}
{'tag5': ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9'], 'tag6': ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']}
```

additional request:

```
tags, attributes = [], []
for i in localNames:
  tags.append(re.findall(r"local-name\(\)='(.*?)'", i))
  attributes.append(re.findall(r"name\(\)='(.*?)'", i))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - may I ask how I can make the tags&attributes a list like your example? Right now the printed tags I get are just like what I showed in my question..

Comment: Hi @galaxyan thank you so much! It's very promising! I tried the additional request codes and find that if I print attributes, it prints out several separate lists with the last one printing out everything, which is what we need/same as your example. I'm trying to figure out how to only print out the one we need now...

Comment: Sorry my bad! I found the reason why I got that result. please ignore my last message.

Comment: It works great now! Thank you!! I'll mark this as the answer then. But I'll try to read/understand the codes my tomorrow as now it's kind of late and if I have any questions, can I get back to you tomorrow?

Comment: @Penny sure,let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily and clearly if you explicitly create the dictionaries. `zip` doesn't create a dictionary.

```
tags = [
    ['tag1'],
    ['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'],
    ['tag5', 'tag6']
]

attributes = [
    ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4'],
    ['attribute5', 'attribute6'],
    ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']
]

dict_list = []
for t_list, a_list in zip(tags, attributes):
    for t in t_list:
        dict_list.append({t: a_list})
        print(dict_list[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - may I ask how I can make the tags&attributes a list like your example? Right now the printed tags I get are just like what I showed in my question...

Comment: In my example, the tags and attributes are stored in the list called `dicts`. I'll rename that to `dict_list` so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
guten_tag = { tag: attributes[i] for i, tag_group in enumerate(tags) for tag in tag_group}
```

make sure you have a list called `tags` and a list called `attributes` like in the other examples.

```
tags = [
    ['tag1'],
    ['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'],
    ['tag5', 'tag6']
]

attributes = [
    ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4'],
    ['attribute5', 'attribute6'],
    ['attribute7', 'attribute8', 'attribute9']
]
```

**Speed comparison:**

`galaxy_an` answer is `1.05 µs per loop` at `1000000 loops` using the `timeit` module

`jeremy` answer is `1.21 µs` at `1000000 loops` using the `timeit` module

`guten_tag`(this method) is `850 ns per loop` at `1000000 loops` using the `timeit`module

where `µs` is `10 ^ -6`  and `nano` is `10 ^ -9`.

On a very superficial level, this gives you 2-3 order of magnitude performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by applying nested `maps`:

```
map(
    lambda x: map(
        lambda y: {y: attributes[x[0]]},
        x[1]
    ), 
    enumerate(tags)
)
```

Comment: I've tried running this and it gives me `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Comment: @Conic Updated the answer. Looking forward to your performance estimation for this solution!

Comment: I'm trying to carefully rephrase this as a function that accepts attributes, tags, and returns a dictionary. I notice that there are several steps I'd have to take that might significantly alter the performance estimation. If you wouldn't mind, can you find a way to turn your map into a dictionary?

Comment: @Conic It shouldn't output a single dict, instead it should output a list of dicts, as the OP asked for. If you are concerned about `map` vs `list` in Python 3 then just cast it to a `list`. If you're trying to output a single dict then you probably misunderstood the question.